# need help in Asp.net 3.5 sp1 routing

Tags: asp.net, routes, redirect

I need to change the url with product name using the `querystring id`
e.g `www.somedomain.com/Details.aspx?id=256&mc=2`
should change in to `www.somedomain.com/Details/mens/helmets`

Note: I'm not using MVC architecture

Comment: Right. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Http Handlers` and `HttpContext.RewritePath`in order to re write your url